# Verify if $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider a random variable $X$ and a sequence of random variables $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that the distribution of $(X_{n},X)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 0, X = 0) = \dfrac{n}{3(n + 1)}\\\\
\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 0, X = 1) = \dfrac{1}{3}\\\\
\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 1, X = 0) = \dfrac{1}{3(n + 1)}\\\\
\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 1, X = 1) = \dfrac{1}{3}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Verify if $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $X$.

Here is my attempt.

Based on the given information, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 0, X = 0) + \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 0, X = 1) = \frac{n}{3(n + 1)} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2n + 1}{3(n + 1)}\\\\
&\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 1, X = 0) + \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 1,X = 1) = \frac{1}{3(n + 1)} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{n + 2}{3(n + 1)}\\\\
&\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X = 0, X_{n} = 0) + \mathbb{P}(X = 0, X_{n} = 1) = \frac{n}{3(n + 1)} + \frac{1}{3(n + 1)} = \frac{1}{3}\\\\
&\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X = 1, X_{n} = 0) + \mathbb{P}(X = 1, X_{n} = 1) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

We say that $X_{n}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}}X$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ the following limit equals zero:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega : |X_{n}(\omega) - X(\omega)| \geq \varepsilon\}) = 0.
\end{align*}

But the I got stuck. Could someone help me to finish the exercise?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0,X=1)=1/3$, what does this imply for the limit when $\varepsilon<1$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Since $\{\omega\in\Omega: |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|\geq 1\}\supset\{\omega\in\Omega: X_n(\omega)=0, X(\omega)=1\}$, we have
$$\mathbb P(|X_n-X|\geq 1)\geq \mathbb P(X_n=0, X_n=1)=\frac13\not\to0.$$